# Are there nice dissection proofs of the Pythagorean Theorem which dissect something unusual?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof

There is a large class of proofs of the Pythagorean Theorem which show that a square of side length $c$ can be dissected into squares of side lengths $a$ and $b$.

There is also the proof which shows that the right triangle itself can be dissected into similar triangles whose hypotenuses have length $a$ and $b$.

Are there any natural-looking proofs which dissect some shape other than a square or right triangle, like a dissection of an equilateral triangle of side length $c$ into equilateral triangles of side lengths $a$ and $b$? (By Bolyai's theorem we know that such a dissection exists, but it might be really painful to construct...)

Comment: (Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571578/jigsaw-style-proofs-of-the-pythagorean-theorem-with-non-square-squares, except that my second paragraph excludes the answer given.)

Comment: This may not be sufficiently "unusual", but ... U.S. President James Garfield devised a [proof by dissection of a trapezoid](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasure-james-a-garfields-proof-of-the-pythagorean-theorem) (MAA.org).

Comment: For something insufficiently "natural-looking" ... Any proof involving dissecting the squares on each side of a right triangle converts to an equilateral triangle in the following way: Apply compatible linear transformations to the squares to turn them into $60^\circ$-$120^\circ$ rhombi. Cutting along each short diagonal gives a pair of equilateral triangles; duplicating each pair gives four triangles, which assemble into a single triangle twice as large. Scale by $1/2$ for triangles of side-length $a$, $b$, $c$.